# How to access state from multiple contexts in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using the context API to share state across many components in my application. I have a couple of different context files that I wrap as providers around my root level component. I'm curious how to use multiple context hooks within the same functional component. See below:

```
import { Context as EpisodeContext } from "../context/EpisodeContext";
import { Context as PlaybackContext } from "../context/PlaybackContext";

const EpisodeDetailsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state } = useContext(PlaybackContext);
  const { state } = useContext(EpisodeContext)

....omitted for brevity.....
}
```

This code obviously doesn't work when I destructure the second state variable it is already defined above.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just got name collision, its not related to React, try renaming one of the variables:

```
const { state } = useContext(PlaybackContext);
const { state: state2 } = useContext(EpisodeContext) // use state2 now
```

Comment: awesome. generally fairly new to js so figured there was some syntax for it.